# Using matplot in R - Want to create plot using CVS data

Tags: r, graph, plot

I have 12 treatments that each have 10 measurements that I want to plot against time.

My CVS file looks like this (just a few lines, the total number of rows is 480, 48 observations)

```
- block observations      soil      oil days weight
- 1       1            1 untreated  untreated    1    205
- 2       1            1 untreated  untreated    2    200
- 3       1            1 untreated  untreated    3    160
- 4       1            1 untreated  untreated    4    120
- 5       1            1 untreated  untreated    5     90
- 6       1            1 untreated  untreated    6     50
- 7       1            1 untreated  untreated    7     40
- 8       1            1 untreated  untreated    8     35
- 9       1            1 untreated  untreated    9     30
- 10      1            1 untreated  untreated   10     15
```

My R code looks like this:

```
matplot(matrix(weightData$weight, 10, 15), type="l",col=rep(c(1,4), each=10), lwd=2,lty=rep(c(1,2), each=10),xlab="Days", ylab="Weights", cex.lab=1.4)
```

Is there a way to have the 12 lines have different colors?

I'm not sure about my legend either....I copied code from a class tutorial and tried adjusting it with my own data but it doesn't come out properly.

```
legend(legend = colnames 1,10,c("Untreated-Untreated", "Untreated-Metals", "Untreated-Metalsx2" etc etc...),lty=c(2,5), col=c(4,1))
```

The output looks like it is getting there but I'm still not sure how to fix my code to make it appear properly.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXquE.png

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Don't blindly copy. Read the help files for every command or function you wish to use.  Do you even understand what `col=rep(c(1,4), each=10)` is doing?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it does not show any effort.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need `matplot`? Have you tried `ggplot2`? This is what I would suggest.

1) First of all install `ggplot2` for plotting and `reshape2` to deal with the dataframe:

```
install.packages(c('ggplot2','reshape2'))
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
```

2) Now we "melt" your CSV dataframe. I couldn't understood what are your *id variables*, but I think its all the variables so: *block*, *observations*, *soil*, *oil* and *days*.
We place those as `id.vars`. The remaining (*weight*) will be the `measure.vars` (for more info type `?melt` for melt documentation).

```
mdf <- melt(mdf, id.vars=c("block", "observations", "soil", "oil", "days"), value.name="Weight")
```

3) Finally we plot using `ggplot2`. Here is a very simple example with *observations* taking the color:

```
ggplot(data=mdf, aes(x=days, y=Weight, group = variable, colour = observations)) +
    geom_line()
```

Hope it helps!